# udev fails to create persistenly named symlink using ID_PATH

Tags: udev

I want to name a (USB) device persistently depending on the port it is connected to.

Using udevadmin I found the following info

```
# udevadm info --name=input/event3 | grep ID_PATH
E: ID_PATH=platform-ci_hdrc.1-usb-0:1.1.4:1.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=platform-ci_hdrc_1-usb-0_1_1_4_1_0
```

So the device seems to have properties ID_PATH and ID_PATH_TAG, which look like what I want.

I added to a matching udev.rule

```
SYMLINK+="foo-%E{ID_PATH_TAG} foo1-$env{ID_PATH} foo2-$env{ID_PATH_TAG}"
```

(The 3 variants were just trying desperately... one should be enough once it works.)

The rule gets executed and the there is no error in the log (log level = debug).

However, the created symbolic links are called

```
/dev/foo-
/dev/foo1-
/dev/foo2-
```

So it looks like the properties ID_PATH and ID_PATH_TAG are not yet set when my rule gets executed. Do I need to pay attention to any ordering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw that existing rules using ID_PATH are all 60-* or higher. Mine was 45-* for no particular except historic reasons.

Renaming my rules file shows that it's the rule number that makes the difference:

1. `59-foo.rules`: ID_PATH/ID_PATH_TAG expand to empty string
2. `60-foo.rules`: ID_PATH/ID_PATH_TAG expand to empty string
3. `61-foo.rules`: ID_PATH/ID_PATH_TAG expand correctly

The explanation is in `60-persistent-input.rules` containing

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="pci|usb|platform|acpi", IMPORT{builtin}="path_id"
```

I could not find documentation for the builtins, but I'm guessing that the path_id builtin puts ID_PATH/ID_PATH_TAG into the environment.

Comment: You can also bring in the path's by adding this just above the `SUBSYSTEMS` line: `ENV{ID_PATH}=="", IMPORT{builtin}="path_id"`

Comment: Yeah it sounds logical that that should work. However, I would not see a good reason to duplicate that code into my own "earlier" rule, if the distro already contains the same code in a "later" rule.

Comment: Agreed. FYI, saw this technique here: https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2017/07/msg01453.html

Answer (score 1):

First run this command to get the list of attributes of your device.

```
udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n <devpath>)
```

then you can do something like this

```
... SYMLINK+=”device_$attr{serial}”, ...
```

sometimes you have to set a environment variable with the data that you need, something like this.

```
... ENV{SERIAL_NUMBER}="$attr{serial_number}"
```

to later use it like this.

```
... SYMLINK+="device_$env{SERIAL_NUMBER}"
```

Comment: What is exactly the difference between an environment variable and an attribute? If there is an attribute, why would I want to set an environment variable first and then use it later instead of just using the attribute in the first place? My udevadm info output showed E:, so I'm guessing ID_PATH is an environment variable.